# what's the tms api to get translate folder

Tags: 2011, translation-manager

When we send a folder for translation to  tms how do we get translate folder checkbox value which is shown on the upper right of the added items tab, in the tms plugin api.

Comment: Can you edit your question and clarify a bit more what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the "checkboxes" of the added Item using this property:

```
AddedItem.TranslationOptions
```